# EF Power Tool - Exclude Tables

Tags: entity-framework

I have managed to tweak the tt templates for the EF power tool to create the code as I like, but one thing I have not been able to do is find a way to exclude certain tables.  For instance, when you add diagram support to your database, it will try to include the system diagram table as well.  I was hoping there was a way to tell the tool to ignore this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting which tables should be used for reverse engineering is currently not possible (Beta 2) but according to ADO.NET team blog it is feature they already have in the backlog so hopefully it will be part of future beta or RTM.

Comment: Cool.  Would be nice if they allow some customization at that level as well, but thanks for the quick response.